# Sound not working on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, nvidia, soundcard, speakers

Using an ASUS TUF FX505GD. My Speakers just stopped working and I think is something to do with my graphics card.

This is what it shows up when I run `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e10 (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a334 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a328 (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev ff)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5003 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

And this is what it shows when I run `aplay --list-devices`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news! I found a solution

It seems to be that this is issue is reported in Ubuntu kernel 5.3.0-41 and -42, you can go into details in this [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061)

Anyway the easiest way to fix it is to:

1. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as root and add options `snd-hda-intel` `dmic_detect=0` at the end of this file by writing this on the terminal:

   ```
   echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as root and add blacklist `snd_soc_skl` at the end of the file by writing this on the terminal:

   ```
   echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
3. Restart the computer