# No Audio Ubuntu 18.04 with HDA Nvidia Card

Tags: nvidia, sound, amixer

So I recently changed from Windows to Ubuntu and I am having sound issues. I don't have any sound at all. I am using NVidia Drivers so I know that may cause issues but I want to know if there is any solution. My `alsamixer` looks like this:

[image: alsamixer]

Also if I do `aplay -l` I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I cant change the volume of S/PDIF and in `alsamixer` when I press F6 I only get the Nvidia card. Please help.

EDIT: When I use `lspci -vnn | grep -iA4 audio` I get:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0949]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
Memory at a5518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at a5200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]

Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, sof_pci_dev

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0949]

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0949]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at a3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact problem a couple weeks ago!!

Here's a [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222600/solved-sound-not-working-on-ubuntu/1223922#1223922) I started with my problem as well, and a solution bellow that I found after intensive work

Hope it fixes yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have wrong driver loaded `Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci`

Try to override it to `snd_hda_intel` with this command:

```
sudo driverctl list-devices
```

You should see your audio device as `0000:1028:0949` you can also shorten the search if you write the loaded driver to be sure:

```
sudo driverctl list-devices | grep sof-audio-pci
```

Then replace loaded driver on device to `snd_hda_intel`

```
sudo driverctl set-override 0000:1028:0949 snd_hda_intel
```

Now you should be fine, type `killall pulseaudio` to refresh it or reboot the system to take effect.

If you don't have `driverctl` utility install it:

```
sudo apt install driverctl
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But when i use `sudo driverctl list-devices` I only get my devices with numbers from 0000:00:00.0 to 0000:04:00.0 although i think my audio device is `0000:01:00.1 snd_hda_intel` should i overwrite this one?

Comment: Run `sudo driverctl list-devices | grep sof-audio-pci` it will show you which device is loaded to. Replace it to `snd_hda_intel`

Comment: Updated in my answer

Comment: I get `driverctl: failed to bind device 0000:00:1f.3 to driver snd_hda_intel`

Comment: Did you try `sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel` ?

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens and i still get the error message. I tried to run it with verbose mode and i got this:
`driverctl: setting driver override for 0000:00:1f.3: snd_hda_intel
driverctl: device 0000:00:1f.3 not bound
driverctl: reprobing driver for 0000:00:1f.3
driverctl: failed to bind device 0000:00:1f.3 to driver snd_hda_intel
`

Comment: Try to reinstall pulseaudio `sudo apt remove --purge pulseaudio` then `sudo apt install pulseaudio` and `killall pulseaudio`